# Express app defined `static` folder not working properly

Tags: express

In my `express` app, I have declared the static folder. And I am keeping my `index.html` as well in the static folder. But I have created a new `router` for a new purpose. when i create a new `router` my static folder always trying to get the assets using the new `router` declared. any one help me to sort this issue?

here is my code and issue :

```
var 
express = require("express"),
app     = express(),
Router  = express.Router;


app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/puplic')); //my public folder

var oneTime = new Router(); //my new router


oneTime.get("*", function( req, res ) {

    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/oneTime/index.html");

});

app.use("/oneTime", oneTime);

app.listen( 9000, function portCallback() {

    console.log(" I am started!!" , __dirname);

})
```

But my app trying to get the `angular` js like this:

> http://localhost:9000/oneTime/oneTime/angular.min.js

what is the issue?

here is the html how i call my angualr:

```
<script src="oneTime/angular.min.js"></script>
```

actually I am expecting like this:

> http://localhost:9000/public/oneTime/angular.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can change this line:

```
app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/puplic')); //my public folder.
```

to

```
app.use('/oneTime', express.static(__dirname + '/puplic')); //my public folder
```

**Option 2**

I am assuming you have a `js` folder in the public folder, then you need to change your html code:

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

and the server code will be

```
app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/puplic')); //my public folder.
```

Comment: Updated with yours, but still no lock. it trying to get script like this : `http://localhost:9000/oneTime/script.js` But my file there in `http://localhost:9000/public/oneTime/script.js`

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require("express"),
var app     = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'puplic')); //my public folder
app.get("*", function( req, res ) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
app.listen( 9000, function portCallback() {
    console.log("Server is Running on 9000");
});
```

Comment: move index.html file from ontime to public folder

Comment: No luck again. still it calls from `http://localhost:9000/oneTime/script.js` - I guess there is some issue in my `router` declaration. can you see it once again

Comment: 2 things.

1) have you move your index.html file in public folder?
2) why you want route a index.html file which is your main file using a express router you could just render the file directly into the browser using above code